# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\array_get() in laravel 6.16

Tags: php, laravel

in my controller I create a function to validate user and notify via mail

```
protected function register(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
        try {
            $validatedData['password']        = bcrypt(array_get($validatedData, 'password'));
            $validatedData['activation_code'] = str_random(30).time();
            $user                             = app(User::class)->create($validatedData);

        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            logger()->error($exception);

            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Unable to create new user.');
        }
        $user->notify(new UserRegisteredSuccessfully($user));

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Successfully created a new account. Please check your email and activate your account.');

    }
```

For some reason, I keep getting this error
**Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\array_get()**
Can someone please teach me how to fix this error ?

Much appreciated in advance.

Comment: Try `\array_get`, since it's trying to use the namespace

Comment: where can I add this please? I'm using this ** namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;**

Comment: At the first line after the try opening block. Instead of `bcrypt(array_get($validatedData, 'password'));`, do: `bcrypt(\array_get($validatedData, 'password'));`, like @anyber mentioned

Comment: okay but I'm getting this error now **Call to undefined function array_get()**

Answer (score 9):

Use `\Arr::get()` instead of `array_get()` in laravel 6. array_get() deprecated in Laravel 6.x. So check this:

```
protected function register(Request $request)
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
    try {
        $validatedData['password']        = bcrypt(\Arr::get($validatedData, 'password'));
        $validatedData['activation_code'] = \Str::random(30).time();
        $user                             = app(User::class)->create($validatedData);

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        logger()->error($exception);

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Unable to create new user.');
    }
    $user->notify(new UserRegisteredSuccessfully($user));

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Successfully created a new account. Please check your email and activate your account.');

}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm getting this error **Call to undefined function str_random()** please how can I get the correct laravel helpers for laravel 6.16

Comment: @TobyNwude check the updated answer. str_random() is also removed in laravel 6.x.